# Setup Xdebug for Laravel on Windows

Tags: php, windows, laravel, visual-studio-code, xdebug

Now I am learning Laravel, but the problem is: when trying to debug blade.php code it does not work, dont hit the breakpoin

Do you know how to make Xdebug work with Laravel?

**OS:**

> Windows 8.1

**Code editor:**

> Visual Studio code

**Route of the laravel project:**

> C:\Users\SleekBook\Proyectos\SistemaEquino

**PHP path:**

> C:\Users\SleekBook\scoop\apps\php\7.2.5\php.ini

**PHP.ini configuration:**

```
zend_extension = "C:\Users\SleekBook\scoop\apps\php\7.2.5\php_xdebug-2.6.0-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll"
[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.show_local_vars = 1
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

[The server local its online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iimjd.png)

```js
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
```